# Decrypt javascript file

Tags: javascript, encryption, hex

I am having an issue with a javascript file that i have never seen before. I dont know how does it even work i am posting some portion of file please help me how can i decrypt such file. This is a task assigned to me i have searched over internet but found nothing

```
$(document)[_0xbad7[169]](function ()
{
    var _0x99f1x1=false;
    var _0x99f1x2=false;
    var _0x99f1x3=false;
    var _0x99f1x4=false;
    var _0x99f1x5=_0xbad7[0];
    var _0x99f1x6=0;
    var _0x99f1x7=1;
    $(_0xbad7[2])[_0xbad7[1]](function (_0x99f1x8)
    {
    }
    );
    function _0x99f1x9()
    {
        $(_0xbad7[5])[_0xbad7[4]](_0xbad7[3],_0xbad7[0]);
        $(_0xbad7[9])[_0xbad7[8]](_0xbad7[6],_0xbad7[7]);
        $(_0xbad7[10])[_0xbad7[8]](_0xbad7[6],_0xbad7[7]);
        $(_0xbad7[11])[_0xbad7[8]](_0xbad7[6],_0xbad7[7]);
        $(_0xbad7[12])[_0xbad7[8]](_0xbad7[6],_0xbad7[7]);
        _0x99f1x7=1;
    }
    ;
    function _0x99f1xa(_0x99f1xb)
    {
        $(_0xbad7[14])[_0xbad7[8]](_0xbad7[13],_0x99f1xb);
    }
    ;
    function _0x99f1xc()
    {
        _0x99f1x1f(_0xbad7[15],_0xbad7[16],_0xbad7[16]);
        _0x99f1x1f(_0xbad7[17],_0xbad7[16],_0xbad7[18]);
        _0x99f1x1f(_0xbad7[19],_0xbad7[16],_0xbad7[20]);
        _0x99f1x1f(_0xbad7[21],_0xbad7[16],_0xbad7[22]);
        _0x99f1x1f(_0xbad7[23],_0xbad7[24],_0xbad7[16]);
        _0x99f1x1f(_0xbad7[25],_0xbad7[24],_0xbad7[18]);
        _0x99f1x1f(_0xbad7[26],_0xbad7[24],_0xbad7[20]);
        _0x99f1x1f(_0xbad7[27],_0xbad7[24],_0xbad7[22]);
    }
    ;
```

Comment: "*This is a task assigned to me*" so why are you asking us to do it? I can do it, but not for free. Also, this file looks obfuscated, so you have to manually clean it and figure out what the variable names mean.

Comment: @Blender - yea.. not to mention the code for _0x99f1x1f isn't even posted!

Comment: Because i have never seen such file before thats why i need help

Comment: @SB ihave mentioned that i am posting some part not the entire code

Answer (score 1):

That code is normal JavaScript code that has been obfuscated using a tool (such as [jsobfuscate](http://www.jsobfuscate.com/index.php)) to make it a pain for anyone who would like to steal or copy it. Technically, if the author took time to try protecting his code, that would mean you are not allowed to use any of that code. However, there are some [tools](http://jsbeautifier.org/) out there that helps to make that mess a bit more understandable, but they still won't figure it out for you.

From what I can quickly see, `0xbad7` is an array that contains most of the function names, selectors, function parameters, etc. One thing you could do is doing an interpolation between the value contained at specific indexes and the `0xbad7[x]` references.

You could easily automate that process using something like teh following, however it won't work very well with object references because you will end up with `[object Object]`, but you could make the solution a bit more intelligent to find out what is the object's constructor and things like this.

Have fun!

http://jsbin.com/#/agikay/1/edit

```
//get a reference to the _0xbad7 array
//and do something like...
var _0xbad7 = ['item0', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
    txt = document.querySelector('textarea');

txt.value = txt.value.replace(/_0xbad7\[(\d+)\]/g, function ($0, $1) {
  return _0xbad7[$1];
});
```

Comment: Tools that you have linked in your answers are used for compressing and decompressing the code but it is in encrypted form... I want to decrypt it.. Anyways thnx for the response

Comment: @ShayanHusaini, No jsbeautifier can also deobfuscate the code to a certain point, but here there is not much it can do with your code, strings are not encoded in hexa form, the variables names have just been changed, but it's quite simple to reverse engineer if you use the approach I provided. Please consider marking this answer as solved.

Comment: I cannot mark your answer as solved because it does not solve my problem... i want to decode the file so i can modify it according to my needs

Comment: @ShayanHusaini, There is no magic tool that will decode it all for you and no one will do it all for your either, you have to work it out, but you should have enough information with my answer to start working on the problem. Have you tried what I explained here http://jsbin.com/#/agikay/1/edit?